# How to specify client certificate when connecting to ASP.NET Core SignalR hub

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, x509certificate2, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a .NET SignalR client (in an ASP.NET Web API 2 project hosted under www.**domain1**.com) that connects to a SignalR hub which is hosted in a .NET Core API project (www.**domain2**.com). Both web projects are hosted under IIS. The API is set up to use JWT Bearer as its default authentication scheme. The .NET client can authenticate successfully with the hub by specifying the `AccessTokenProvider` delegate which essentially calls a login method on the API and returns a JWT token. I'd like to add an extra layer of security by adding a client certificate to the SignalR requests using `ClientCertificates.Add` on the `HttpConnectionOptions` object, but no matter what I try, I can't access the certificate on the receiving end (API). The certificate being retrieved from the store is a full certificate (.pfx). The API is set up to use CORS and I do allow www.**domain1**.com.

Things I've tried:

- Access certificate via `HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate` on the .NET Core API side - This always returns null.
- Using a `WebRequestHandler` with a certificate attached on the client side to make a call to the .NET Core API, just to see if this actually sends through the certificate - This also returns null on the receiving end.
- Configuring the API to use certificates using the steps outlined in [Configure certificate authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
- Specifying the "Require SSL" option in IIS for the API site

Could it be the fact that I am trying to send a certificate cross domain? Is using a certificate for this even something worth doing security-wise? Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the SignalR client set up code:

```
private static HubConnection CreateHubConnection()
 {
        var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        var certificateCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "mythumbprint", false);
        X509Certificate2 cert = certificateCollection[0];

        _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl($"{_url}/signalR", (HttpConnectionOptions options) =>
            {
                // This is what I am trying to get to work
                options.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

                // This works fine, but I'd like to add an extra layer of security by using a certificate
                options.AccessTokenProvider = async () => await TryGetAccessTokenAsync();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging(builder => builder.AddDebug())
            .WithAutomaticReconnect(new MyHubClientRetryPolicy())
            .Build();
} 

private static async Task<string> TryGetAccessTokenAsync()
{
        string signalRLoginDetails = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Username = "username", Password = "password" });

        var content = new StringContent(signalRLoginDetails, Encoding.UTF8, MimeMediaTypeNames.Json);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(_loginUrl, content);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        string token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return token;
   }
```

This is how my API is set up:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Other code omitted for brevity
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret));
        services
            .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidIssuer = appSettings.Issuer,
                    ValidAudience = appSettings.Audience,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = key,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                };

                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accessToken) && path.StartsWithSegments(Constants.SignalR.Endpoint))
                        {
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
    }
```

Comment: `var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);` -- this unlikely is going to work, because this requires local admin permissions, or explicitly delegated permissions to read private key when hosted on a web server. Instead, you should re-deploy the certificate to `CurrentUser` store of app pool your web app uses or explicitly grant read permissions to app pool account.

Comment: I am testing this on my local environment on which the app pool does have access to the certificate. Reading the certificate from the store does in fact retrieve the certificate and the private key is read as well.